# create microsoft project file using C#

Tags: c#, ms-office, ms-project

can I develop a c# application which uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject to create msProject files and then deploy that application on PCs which doesn't have microsoft project installed on them ?
if yes please explain how .

Comment: Circumventing the need to buy project?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't automate the application unless it has been installed on the machine.

Edit: However, there is a open source project to manipulate project files and I don't think that needs to have MS Project installed so might be worth looking at that here: [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/)